# Adding Relevant Post Images

Tags: plugins, images

I want to add relevant posts at the end of each of my posts page **with an image** in my newly created website http://www.techberita.com
But being a beginner this is a great problem for me as I can't do that as I don't have that much knowledge of PHP and wordpress. I search out for plugins but couldn't find a good one for the purpose.
I hope to get a reply soon.

A php code for the purpose is highly preferable.

Comment: what criterium do you want to use to define 'relevant'? posts related by category? by tags? do you want to use the 'featured image' for the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin sounds like what you're looking for. It uses post tags to find all relevant posts.

Upload it to your plugins directory and activate it. Then just decide where you want it on your site and add post tags to get content to relate to each other.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/igit-related-posts-with-thumb-images-after-posts/

Note. I am not the developer of this plugin, just a happy user.

Comment: The problem is that plugins increase up the loading time and can't be easily customized. So, I want to have a **PHP** code only.

Comment: In my experience, the plugin I've recommended doesn't add a lot of overhead. It also includes timthumb for on-the-fly image resizing to make sure it fits your post footer. Given the amount of code required to find all relevant posts, and display them, it would be fitting that it fits in a plugin, rather than functions.php. Worst case, download the plugin and dissect its PHP to see if you can trim it down to your needs.

Comment: @LakshayGoel, adding code means "doing more stuff" so *any code* will cause some reduction in performance, but a well written plugin will not cause any more performance problems than code you cook up yourself, and since you claim to be a beginner a plugin may well perform better than your code.